# How to get a longer \nmid

Tags: math-mode

I find the `\mid` is a little short, so I alway use `\,\big|\,` instead of `\mid`. But I don’t know how to make a longer `\nmid`. `\not\mid` or `\not |` obviously doesn’t produce `\nmid`, so the what I did for longer `\mid` doesn’t work. Could you give me some ideas? Thanks!

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117035/82917) to a slightly different question provides a possible workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime I hope that you excuse me if I reply your question with these links, but I think that they help you to find half answer: [Why does \big\mid not work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239242/why-does-big-mid-not-work), [\middle too big](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181091/middle-too-big).

Here my MWE using `scalerel` package to have a big `\nmid`. Into `\scaleobj{...}` you can put a scale factor.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{scalerel}


\begin{document}
\[a\mathbin{\scaleobj{1}{\nmid}} b\]
\[\begin{Vmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
a & b & c
\end{Vmatrix}\mathbin{\scaleobj{2}{\nmid}} \begin{Vmatrix}
7 & 2 & 1\\
a & b & c
\end{Vmatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]